# What is the registry key associated with the "Allow remote connections" parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any?, What another scriptable process to modify it you do know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the "allow remote connections" setting in management studio?
[image: link text]

I'm guessing you dont want this.  This option turns on the `sp_configure 'remote access' , 1` [option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187660.aspx), which is an old feature of SQL Server that pre-dates linked servers.

What you actually want is this: [How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)  *(the naming convention here isn't at all confusing!)*

In which case, yes there's a registry key.  Assuming you only have a default instance installed, then the registry path is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib
```

with a key for each protocol. eg. tcp, sm (shared memory) np (named pipes)

A value of enabled is set to 1 inside each key of tcp or np, depending on what you want enabled.

The easiest way (for me at least) is to script this with [xp_regwrite](http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Undoc/UndocExtSP.htm) which is an undocumented stored procedure, but does the job & means you can include it with your other sql server configuration scripts that run in sqlcmd/SSMS after an install is performed.

eg:

```
exec master..xp_regwrite
     'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
     ,'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp'
     ,'Enabled'
     ,'REG_DWORD'
     ,1
```